# Reading data from an excel file using PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet in symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony4

I develop an application with symfony 4 and I need to read data from an excel file. I integrate PhpOffice \ PhpSpreadsheet in my project but I can not find documentation to use it for now. I find this site to start but it does not do everything I want. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/

If someone would have another track or know how to read data from an excel file using PhpSpreadsheet.

```
public function excelReader(){

    $reader = new Xlsx();
    $reader->setReadDataOnly(TRUE);
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load("test.xlsx");
    $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); 
    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); 
    $highestColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
$res = array();
    for($row=1; $row < $highestRow ; $row++){
        for($col = 1; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; $col++){
            $value = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col,$row)->getValue();
            array_push($res,$value);
        }
    }


    return $this->render('table/excel.html.twig', [
        'list' => $res,
    ]);

 }
```

in this code I try to load and then read the test.xlsx file that I put in the controller folder. I get the following error: File "test.xlsx" does not exist.

Comment: Please show us what you have done, you need to share some code in order to help

Comment: Those are the official PHPSpreadsheet documents, if they can't help you I doubt we can. Have you tried anything as of yet? Without some idea of what you're trying to achieve we won't be able to help.

Comment: You really need to provide more info. "it does not do everything I want" does not tell us anything. What do you want it to do? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the folder {symfony folder}/public/uploads/ and put test.xlsx in that folder.
Then change this line in your code:
`$spreadsheet = $reader->load("uploads/test.xlsx");`
(The folder {symfony folder}/src/Controller/ is for code only for security reasons.)

There are examples of reading spreadsheets under
{symfony directory}/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/samples/Reader/

Comment: Thank you so much. I am a beginner with symfony and I was not aware of this security feature